# Fragment and Host Activity Commnication

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this design problem. I have an activity which hosts two fragment and any given point of time only one activity is visible.

**Activity A hosts Fragment B and Fragment C**

Host Activity A implements FragmentCommunicator interface and implement respond(int code) method using this method communicator both Fragment B and C can talk to host Activity.

Now here is the problem.

In onClick of Host activity I check certain condition and based on that I take decision which fragment to show.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.some_button
              if(authNotedone)
                  showFragmentA();
              else{
                  EDIT: //setting some properties before showing Fragment B
                  showFragmentB();     
              }
    }
}
```

So far it works fine. If condition is true FragmentA will be visible with login form. After successful login I would like to show fragment B again. How can I achieve this.

What I have tried?

1) After successful login Fragment A send message to Host activity using Fragmentcommunicator's respond(code) method but it was ugly design as I have to either call performClick() or call showFragmentA()  in respond method if code is success.

There could be multiple such conditions in my program How I can handle these neatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a interface as a call back to the activity. Once you get the message in the activity there is no need to click the button just replace the existing fragment in the container.

Implement the interface in the activity

```
 FragmentB newFragment = new FragmentB();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putInt("key", "message");
 newFragment.setArguments(args);
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
 // replace with fragmentb. no need to perform click again.
 // based on the message you decide which fragment you want to replace with 
 transaction.commit();
```

You can find an example @

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks Raghu for quick response. this what I am doing but problem arises when I want to set certain properties and initialization before showing FragmentB. See my edit.

Comment: @user2095470 what is the problem you do your initialization before itself. communicate a success a message to activity. based on success message replace with fragmentb.

Comment: Thanks for directing me in right direction. I did some design changes and it is working fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to navigate between fragments? If so, why don't you implement navigation tabs, have a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs).